# Batch text shuffling system

Tags: string, batch-file

I have a text string which is user definable in length
 As example the user has entered 1234567890

What I want is to pull out every first character followed by every 3rd character

So we get the following

```
1st  | 1234567890 = 1
3rd  | 234567890  = 14
1st  | 23567890   = 142
3rd  | 3567890    = 1426
1st  | 357890     = 14263
3rd  | 57890      = 142638
1st  | 5790       = 1426385
3rd  | 790        = 14263850
1st  | 79         = 142638507
3rd  | 9          = 1426385079
```

I also need to account for the e fact that in the end the last two numbers will have less then three digits.

Anyone ideas on how I could achieve this in batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where [batch string manipulation](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) gets really useful:

```
@echo off
set str="1234567890"

for %%a in (%str%) do set str=%%~a
set newstr=
:Loop
set "first=%str:~0,1%"
set "fourth=%str:~3,1%"
set "str=%str:~1,2%%str:~4%"
set "newstr=%newstr%%first%%fourth%"
if not "%fourth%"=="" goto Loop
set "newstr=%newstr%%str:~1%%str:~0,1%

echo.%newstr%
```

For the example input `1234567890` from your question, the output would be indeed:

```
1426385079
```

#### Explanation

This code works using a loop (which is somewhat of an equivalent to a `while` loop in C).

In every iteration of the loop the first and fourth characters are extracted from `str` and appended to `newstr`, which will eventually hold the final output.
Next, `str` is then updated by appending the following two substrings:

- `%str:~1,2%` extracts two characters starting from the second character (indices start from 0, so the second index is 1).
- `%str:~4%` extracts all characters starting from the fifth

The new value of `str` is basically the old value, without the first and fourth characters.

The loop stops when `str` holds three or less characters, (that is when`fourth` is an empty string!). After the loop, the last (three or less) characters are dealt with and appended to `newstr` in the correct order -- this is that special case that you wanted to account for.

Hope that helps!

Comment: gee all i came up with was :

Comment: REM GETS USSERS INPUT...
set ORIGINAL=123456789
REM gets the first character in the string...resulat should be 1
SET PH_1=%original:~0,1%

SET NEW_STRING_BUILD=%PH_1%
MSG * %NEW_STRING_BUILD%
SET FIRSTCHAR=%original:~1%

MSG * %FIRSTCHAR%
GOTO MY_LOOP
:MY_LOOP
SET PH_3=%FIRSTCHAR:~2,1%

MSG * %PH_3%

REM builds new string...result is 14
SET NEW_STRING_BUILD=%NEW_STRING_BUILD%%PH_3%

SET FIRSTCHAR=%original:~2%

MSG * %FIRSTCHAR%
msg * %NEW_STRING_BUILD%
SET PH_4=%FIRSTCHAR:~0,1%
SET NEW_STRING_BUILD=%PH_4%
MSG * %NEW_STRING_BUILD%
SET FIRSTCHAR=%original:~1%
MSG * %FIRSTCHAR%
GOTO MY_LOOP

Comment: @BartvanTuÿl I think still have a mistake, for example for an input like "12345". I'm working on a fix now.

Comment: EitanT Im gona be a real pain but I'm so impressed could you perhaps give a few remarks inbetween on how it works (particularaly qua lines set "lstr=%str:~1,2%"
set "mstr=%str:~4,-1%"

Comment: @BartvanTuÿl Sure, I've added some remarks (note that I had simplified the code so `mstr` and `lstr` are no longer in it...)